# Slow Execution of Function - DataOutPutStream

Tags: java, android, dataoutputstream

```
private void sendCommand(String cmd) {
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes(cmd);
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


String cmd = "/system/bin/input tap 244 580\n";
sendCommand(cmd);
Log.d("Tap","first");
sendCommand(cmd);
Log.d("Tap","second");
```

09-06 01:09:**43.878** 13600-13600/com.example.na D/Tap: first

09-06 01:09:**46.178** 13600-13600/com.example.na D/Tap: second

It's really very slow, I wanted to emulate like a double tap with a delay of maybe 200MS inbetween two taps. but the fastest it can do is 3 seconds ..... Please advice.

**Update** - Tried this , still the delay between each tap is there, faster though.

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
            cmd = "/system/bin/input tap 244 580\n";
            os.writeBytes(cmd);
            cmd = "/system/bin/input tap 244 580\n";
            os.writeBytes(cmd);
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            process.waitFor();
```

Comment: You're opening a pseudo-interactive session in which to run each command.  How about opening only one session in which to run both commands?

Comment: @JohnBollinger updated my question.

Comment: DataOutputStream is for writing binary data. I suggest you use PrintStream which is for text.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not the command itself that introduces the delay?

Comment: @PeterLawrey cant seem to find an example with that

Comment: DataOutputStream is only the right choice if the program you are running is reading a DataInputStream, otherwise something else is likely to be better.

Comment: google `PrintStream example` finds 110,000 results.

Comment: try PrintStream /system/bin/input